# Rendering Issue On Some Devices in ViewPager

Tags: android, android-viewpager, rendering, picasso

I have a ViewPager which it loads an image in each page with Picasso library (used RoundedImageView instead of ImageView) , it works just fine but on  some devices like XPeria z randomly after some time without activity on page, it reflects one of image on background of whole activity , it works fine again when i run the app again. i dn't know how to handle this event(for example this issue doesn't occur on Nexus 7). any advice would be appreciated.

Comment: I faced with the same problem, any workarounds available now?